# Piwik: import gives [Error 111] Connection refused

Tags: matomo

While importing logs in piwik, I get following error in output file :

```
Fatal error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
You can restart the import of <LOG_FILE_NAME> from the point it failed by specifying --skip=283307 on the command line.
```

This happens randomly. Please suggest what can I check and how can I debug the issue.